# GULP. Обновление бразура при изменении файлов на сервере

Tags: gulp, openserver

Вношу изменения через FTP в код .css  который расположен на сервере. Как мне настроить Gulp что бы он отслеживал изменения на сервере и обновлял мне браузер?

спасибо

нынешняя настройка

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost", // проксирование  удаленного сервера
    logPrefix: 'webserver', // префикс  
    host:      'тут мой IP', 
    port:      80, // порт через который будет проксироваться сервер
    open: 'external', //  
    notify:    true,
    ghost:     true,
});

gulp.watch("./css/style.css").on('change', browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch("./*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);

});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync']);
```